# How to verify static void method has been called with power mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, static-methods

I am using the following.

```
Powermock-mockito 1.5.12
Mockito 1.95
junit 4.11
```

Here is my utils class

```
public void InternalUtils {
    public static void sendEmail(String from, String[] to, String msg, String body) {
    }
}
```

here is gist of the class under test:

```
public class InternalService {
       public void processOrder(Order order) {
           if (order.isSuccessful()) {
               InternalUtils.sendEmail(...);
           }
       }
}
```

And here is the test:

```
@PrepareForTest({InternalUtils.class})
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class InternalService {
   public void verifyEmailSend() {
        mockStatic(Internalutils.class);
        doNothing().when(InternalUtils, "sendEmail", anyString(), any(String.class), anyString(), anyString());
        Order order = mock(Order.class);
        when(order.isSuccessful()).thenReturn(true);
        InternalService is = new InternalService();

        verifyStatic(times(1));
        is.processOrder(order);
   }
}
```

The above test fails. The verification mode given is none, but according to the code, if order is successful than email must be send.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

If you are mocking the behavior (with something like `doNothing()`) there should really be no need to call to `verify*()`. That said, here's my stab at re-writing your test method:

```
@PrepareForTest({InternalUtils.class})
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class InternalServiceTest { //Note the renaming of the test class.
   public void testProcessOrder() {
        //Variables
        InternalService is = new InternalService();
        Order order = mock(Order.class);

        //Mock Behavior
        when(order.isSuccessful()).thenReturn(true);
        mockStatic(Internalutils.class);
        doNothing().when(InternalUtils.class); //This is the preferred way
                                               //to mock static void methods.
        InternalUtils.sendEmail(anyString(), anyString(), anyString(), anyString());

        //Execute
        is.processOrder(order);            

        //Verify
        verifyStatic(InternalUtils.class); //Similar to how you mock static methods
                                           //this is how you verify them.
        InternalUtils.sendEmail(anyString(), anyString(), anyString(), anyString());
   }
}
```

I grouped into four sections to better highlight what is going on:

#### 1. Variables

I choose to declare any instance variables / method arguments / mock collaborators here. If it is something used in multiple tests, consider making it an instance variable of the test class.

#### 2. Mock Behavior

This is where you define the behavior of all of your mocks. You're setting up return values and expectations here, prior to executing the code under test. Generally speaking, if you set the mock behavior here you wouldn't need to verify the behavior later.

#### 3. Execute

Nothing fancy here; this just kicks off the code being tested. I like to give it its own section to call attention to it.

#### 4. Verify

This is when you call any method starting with `verify` or `assert`. After the test is over, you check that the things you wanted to have happen actually did happen. That is the biggest mistake I see with your test method; you attempted to verify the method call before it was ever given a chance to run. Second to that is you never specified *which* static method you wanted to verify.

#### Additional Notes

This is mostly personal preference on my part. There is a certain order you need to do things in but within each grouping there is a little wiggle room. This helps me quickly separate out what is happening where.

I also highly recommend going through the examples at the following sites as they are very robust and can help with the majority of the cases you'll need:

- https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Mockito (PowerMock Overview / Examples)
- http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/Mockito.html (Mockito Overview / Examples)

Comment: verifyStatic(times(1)); == verifyStatic();

Comment: Indeed it does: http://powermock.googlecode.com/svn/docs/powermock-1.5.4/apidocs/org/powermock/api/mockito/PowerMockito.html#verifyStatic()

Comment: I was trying to verify that a static method which returns void was called exactly once (with some specific arguments). I had to remove the doNothing statement from the code above in order to get it to work.

Comment: How can I check if a particular static method is called twice but another one is called single time?

Comment: @GaneshSatpute you'll end up doing the `verifyStatic()` call twice, once for the first method (followed by the first method call) and again for the second method (followed by the second method call). For the method that gets called twice, pass in `times(2)` to `verifyStatic()`.

Comment: In my powermock (version 1.7.3 I suppose later as well), verifyStatic() is deprecated. The method is verifyStatic(Class<T> mockedClass) or verifyStatic(mockedClass, Mockito.times(1))

Comment: @WillieZ Good to know! It's been a few years since I posted this. I'll work on updating the answer to use something more current.

Comment: @WillieZ Updated.

Comment: What if I'm using Robolectric?

Comment: Not sure how that applies to this question. Perhaps post a new question?

Comment: It is not working when multiple test cases need to verify the same static void method invocation. Let's say that there are two test cases that need to verify the same static void method, then only one of the either is passing and another one is failing. Both the test cases pass when they are alone (not mutually together), but not together. Any solution for that?

Comment: Are your tests running in parallel? IIRC, that can cause issues with static mocks/verification.

Comment: Thanks, but **not worked**, any idea about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71455593/notamockexception-exception-when-trying-to-verify-a-static-method-with-powermock)?

Comment: @harry it looks like you have an accepted answer on your question.

Comment: Actually it was not an exact solution and if you share or post your suggestion, I would really be appreciated. Regards

Comment: "If you are mocking the behavior (with something like doNothing())". That is simply not true. With methods returning void (doNothing case), the only way to know that method was called is to call verify().

Comment: You left important context off that quote. The full statement was "If you are mocking the behavior (with something like doNothing()) there should really be no need to call to verify*()". My argument here is: it's not very useful to know a mocked void method was called for the purposes of verifying the rest of the function. If you want to do so, you surely can.

Answer (score 25):

Thou the above answer is widely accepted and well documented, I found some of the reason to post my answer here :-

```
    doNothing().when(InternalUtils.class); //This is the preferred way
                                           //to mock static void methods.
    InternalUtils.sendEmail(anyString(), anyString(), anyString(), anyString());
```

Here, I dont understand why we are calling InternalUtils.sendEmail ourself.
I will explain in my code why we don't need to do that.

```
mockStatic(Internalutils.class);
```

So, we have mocked the class which is fine.
Now, lets have a look how we need to verify the sendEmail(/..../) method.

```
@PrepareForTest({InternalService.InternalUtils.class})
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class InternalServiceTest {

    @Mock
    private InternalService.Order order;

    private InternalService internalService;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        internalService = new InternalService();
    }

    @Test
    public void processOrder() throws Exception {

        Mockito.when(order.isSuccessful()).thenReturn(true);
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(InternalService.InternalUtils.class);

        internalService.processOrder(order);

        PowerMockito.verifyStatic(times(1));
        InternalService.InternalUtils.sendEmail(anyString(), any(String[].class), anyString(), anyString());
    }

}
```

These two lines is where the magic is,
First line tells the PowerMockito framework that it needs to verify the class it statically mocked. But which method it need to verify ??
Second line tells which method it needs to verify.

```
PowerMockito.verifyStatic(times(1));
InternalService.InternalUtils.sendEmail(anyString(), any(String[].class), anyString(), anyString());
```

This is code of my class, **sendEmail** api twice.

```
public class InternalService {

    public void processOrder(Order order) {
        if (order.isSuccessful()) {
            InternalUtils.sendEmail("", new String[1], "", "");
            InternalUtils.sendEmail("", new String[1], "", "");
        }
    }

    public static class InternalUtils{

        public static void sendEmail(String from, String[]  to, String msg, String body){

        }

    }

    public class Order{

        public boolean isSuccessful(){
            return true;
        }

    }

}
```

As it is calling twice you just need to change the verify(times(2))... that's all.

Comment: Thanks, but **not worked**, any idea about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71455593/notamockexception-exception-when-trying-to-verify-a-static-method-with-powermock)?