# How to test the number of times a static method in Java is called?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, powermockito

I have a class with `methodA()` that eventually calls a static `methodB()` that returns a String. `methodA()` can cause multiple invocations of `methodB()`, depending on the scenario.

I want to write a unit test to verify that a single invocation of `methodA()` will only result in a single invocation `methodB()`.

How can this be done? I looked at PowerMockito but wasn't able to find suitable examples.

```
class classA {
   public int methodA() {
      // Do something that invokes a method that in turn calls B.methodB()
   }
}

class classB {
   public static String methodB(String str) {
      // Do something
   }
}
```

Comment: Keep a `static` count of the calls?

Comment: maybe powermockito#verifystatic is what you need

Comment: Don't use static methods it's bad practice. Refactor your code and you don't need to do this.

Comment: Shouldn't helper methods that don't manipulate instance variables be static?

Answer (score 0):

To verify a static method call `Mockito` is not sufficient. You would need to use `PowerMockito`.

Before adding `PowerMockito` to your project I would suggest considering to change the static method and use a singleton with an instance method instead.

See this: [How to verify static void method has been called with power mockito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18466198/how-to-verify-static-void-method-has-been-called-with-power-mockito)

Comment: Thanks, I am looking at `PowerMockito`. If possible, can you give an example. Would it be possible to do this without making the static method an instance method?

Comment: See the link. There are plenty of questions about this, yours is kind of a duplicate..

Comment: Interestingly, `verifyStatic(times(n))` is always true for me where `n` is any random +ve integer.