# How to verify arguments passed to a static function with Java JUnit and Mockito (Spring Boot)

Tags: java, spring-boot, mocking, mockito, powermockito

I'm new to all the mentioned technologies so it might be a stupid question.

We have a spring boot application where we need to write to a PostgreSQL-Database via JDBC. 
Therefore we need the static `DriverManager.getConnection()` method to open the connection.

Now in my unit tests I don't want to call this class directly. 
Instead I want to check, that the `DriverManager.getConnection()` is called with the correct String as that is my expected observable external behavior.

I encapsulated this behavior into a `ConnectionFactory` with the method `newConnection(ConnectionType.POSTGRESQL)` because we got more than one Database to use in this Application.

Now I can't find a way to verify via Mockito that this external dependency was called with the correct `String` like you could with an instance:

```
DriverManager dm = mock(DriverManager);

connectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionType.POSTGRESQL);

verify(dm).getConnection("theConnectionStringToBeExpected");
```

**So how to do this with the static dependency?**

I tried the `Captor`-way but this seems to only work for direct usage like

```
mockStatic(DriverManager.class);

final ArgumentCaptor<String> captor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(String.class);

// What I have to do to verify
DriverManager.getConnection("theActualConnectionString");

// What I would like to do to verify
// connectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionType.POSTGRESQL);

verifyStatic();
StaticService.getConnection(captor.capture());

assertEquals("theExpectedConnectionString", captor.getValue());
```

**Edit:**

Here is the nasty little workaround which I currently use for another server...

```
public void driverManagerIsCorrectlyCalledForAds() throws Exception {
    mockStatic(DriverManager.class);

    doNothing().when(databaseDriverLoader).load();

    final Connection expectedConnection = mock(Connection.class);
    when(DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:extendedsystems:advantage://server:1337/database_name;user=user;password=password;chartype=ansi"))
            .thenReturn(expectedConnection);

    Connection actualConnection = connectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionType.ADS);

    assertEquals(expectedConnection, actualConnection);
}
```

**Edit 2:**

**TestClass:**

```
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Ignore;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunnerDelegate;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.mockito.Matchers.anyString;
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.*;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PowerMockRunnerDelegate(SpringRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ConnectionFactory.class, DriverManager.class, DatabaseDriverInformation.class})
public class ConnectionFactoryTest {

    @InjectMocks
    ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;

    @Mock
    DatabaseDriverInformation databaseDriverInformation;

    @Mock
    DatabaseProperties databaseProperties;

    @Mock
    DatabaseProperties.Pg pg;

    @Mock
    DatabaseDriverLoader databaseDriverLoader;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {    
        doReturn(pg).when(databaseProperties).getPg();
        doReturn("server").when(ads).getServer();
        doReturn(1338).when(ads).getPort();
        doReturn("database_name").when(ads).getDatabasename();
        doReturn("user").when(ads).getUser();
        doReturn("password").when(ads).getPassword();
    }

    @Test
    public void driverManagerIsCorrectlyCalledForPg() throws Exception {
        mockStatic(DriverManager.class);
        doNothing().when(databaseDriverLoader).load();

        Connection expectedConnection = mock(Connection.class);
        when(DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://server:1338/database_name;user=user;password=password"))
                .thenReturn(expectedConnection);

        Connection actualConnection = connectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionType.POSTGRESQL);

        assertEquals(expectedConnection, actualConnection);
    }
}
```

**Class under Test:**

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.sql.*;

@Service()
public class ConnectionFactory {

    @Autowired
    private DatabaseDriverLoader databaseDriverLoader;

    @Autowired
    DatabaseProperties databaseProperties;


    public Connection newConnection(ConnectionType connectionType) {
        databaseDriverLoader.load();
        final String connectionString = connectionStringFor(connectionType);
        try {
            return DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString);
        } catch (SQLException sqlException) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Couldn't connect to Server");
        }

    }

    private String connectionStringFor(ConnectionType connectionType) {
        switch (connectionType) {
            case ADS:
                return this.adsConnectionString();
            case POSTGRESQL:
                return this.pgConnectionString();

            default:
                throw new RuntimeException("Invalid connection Type requested!");
        }
    }


    private String adsConnectionString() {
        return new StringBuilder()
                .append("jdbc:extendedsystems:advantage://")
                .append(databaseProperties.getAds().getServer())
                .append(":")
                .append(databaseProperties.getAds().getPort())
                .append("/")
                .append(databaseProperties.getAds().getDatabasename())
                .append(";user=")
                .append(databaseProperties.getAds().getUser())
                .append(";password=")
                .append(databaseProperties.getAds().getPassword())
                .append(";chartype=ansi")
                .toString();
    }

    private String pgConnectionString() {
        return new StringBuilder()
                .append("jdbc:postgresql://")
                .append(databaseProperties.getPg().getServer())
                .append(":")
                .append(databaseProperties.getPg().getPort())
                .append("/")
                .append(databaseProperties.getPg().getDatabasename())
                .append("?user=")
                .append(databaseProperties.getPg().getUser())
                .append("&password=")
                .append(databaseProperties.getPg().getPassword())
                .toString();
    }
}
```

I removed the package-names, some specific imports and some unnecessary tests which are working.

Comment: can you show the full class where you have this piece of code and also your TestClass declaration(how r you setting up PowerMockito)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some search I found this: [How to verify static void method has been called with power mockito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18466198/how-to-verify-static-void-method-has-been-called-with-power-mockito#)

**In Essence:**

**first**:

```
mockStatic(ClassWithStaticFunctionToVerify.class)
```

**second**:

```
Execute the Code that will call the function you want to verify later
```

**third**:

```
verifyStatic();
ClassWithStaticFunctionToVerify.functionYouWantToVerify("ParameterValueYouExpect");
```

With it's help I got the following Solution which works fine:

```
@Test
public void driverManagerIsCorrectlyCalledForPg() throws Exception {
    // Arrange
    mockStatic(DatabaseProperties.Pg.class);
    doReturn(pg).when(databaseProperties).getPg();
    doReturn("server").when(pg).getServer();
    doReturn(1338).when(pg).getPort();
    doReturn("database_name").when(pg).getDatabasename();
    doReturn("user").when(pg).getUser();
    doReturn("password").when(pg).getPassword();

    mockStatic(DriverManager.class);
    doNothing().when(databaseDriverLoader).loadAdsDriverClass();
    doNothing().when(databaseDriverLoader).loadPgDriverClass();

    when(DriverManager.getConnection(anyString())).thenReturn(expectedConnection);

    // Act
    connectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionType.POSTGRESQL);

    // Assert
    verifyStatic();
    DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://server:1338/database_name?user=user&password=password");
}
```

Comment: Did you try passing a wrong parameter and see if test fails?