# Best Way to Write Unit Test for Code Using Thread.sleep

Tags: java

I want to write unit tests to test if the code calls thread.sleep only when certain condition is met. Also this method is called by a framework which has the retry logic so I also want to test a case where the thread is interrupted and the code would work as expected. I figured out a way to wrap the `Thread.Sleep()` in a wrapper class and mock that class to see if the method is called or throw exception for unit test. But I feel it's a overkill to have a wrapper class of thread sleep just for unit tests. Is there a better way to acheieve the same purpose without a wrapper class?

```
 public long sendMessageToDownStream(final Message message) throws StopgapDDBException, InterruptedException {
        if (message.meetCertainCondition()) {
            Thread.sleep(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(msReadFromConfig));
        }  
        //send message to downstream and get messageId.
        messageId = downStream.return();    
        return messageId;
    }
```

Comment: Does it matter if there is a sleep or not - or you rather want to check how long the method is executing?

Comment: Ideally I want to check if the thread sleep is ran or not. But it's fine to check how long the method takes.

Comment: I think you could do it with powermock:
Refs:
https://automationrhapsody.com/verify-static-method-called-powermock/
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18466198/how-to-verify-static-void-method-has-been-called-with-power-mockito

Comment: I think in order to use powermockito, you need run it with @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class) and RunWith only accepts one class but I need to run it with another mock class

Comment: You could use https://github.com/awaitility/awaitility to wrap the call and test the sleep functionality/timeout, then get the return and verify as normal.

Comment: Although a tiny bit brittle, you could just assert that the call to the method takes longer than some duration when the sleep is supposed to happen, and less when it isn’t. If you make the sensitivity low (wide margins) you should be OK

Comment: Probably you should use a retry framework that does the sleeping for you so you don't have to test it.