# How to test that a static method gets called once

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I want to add a check to my test to ensure that my AvailableOptions.calculateAmount() get's called once when my CancelOrderService.generateCancelOrder() method is executed.

```
  @Before
  public void setUp() {
    cancelOrderService = mock(cancelOrderService.class);
    orderDetails = mock(OrderDetails.class);
    cancelOrderInput = mock(CancelOrderInput.class);
    messageChanges = mock(MessageChanges.class);
    availableOptions = mock(AvailableOptions.class);
    service =
        new CancelOrderService(cancelOrderService, messageChanges, cancelOrderInput);
    when(orderDetails.getPremiumSummary()).thenReturn(PremiumSummary.builder().build());
    when(cancelOrderService.requestCancelOrder(any(IContext.class)))
        .thenReturn(orderDetails);
  }

  @Test
  public void service_called() {
    CurrentOrderState currentState = currentOrderState(ORDER_REF);
    TransactionData transactionData = transactionData();
    ContractDetails contractDetails = contractDetails();
    Source source = source();
    service.generateCancelOrder(currentState, source, transactionData, contractDetails);
    verify(cancelOrderService, times(one)).requestCancelOrder(any(IContext.class));
    verifyNoMoreInteractions(cancelOrderService);

    try (MockedStatic<AvailableOptions> availableOptionsMockedStatic = Mockito.mockStatic(AvailableOptions.class)) {
      availableOptionsMockedStatic.when(() -> AvailableOptions.calculateAmount(AvailableOptions.builder().build()))
              .thenReturn("");
      availableOptionsMockedStatic.verify(
        () -> availableOptions.calculateAmount(any(AvailableOptions.class)),
          times(1)
        );
      }
    }
    verifyNoMoreInteractions(cancelOrderService);
  }
```

Above is my setup and test. When I run it I get this error:

> Wanted but not invoked:
> AvailableOptions.class.calculateAmount(
>
> );
> -> at ie.avis.orders.web.AvailableOptions.calculateAmount(AvailableOptions.java:31)
> Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.

I realise that what I'm trying to do is different with a static method but I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. Can anyone please help resolve this issue?

Comment: Generally, if you're trying to test how often a static method is called, you shouldn't be.  It should either be an instance method, or you should be testing that any action taken based on the static method is done correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Mockito has limited support for mocking static calls. You could use Powermockito in addition.

Wit Powermockito, you can do something like `PowerMockito.verifyStatic(times(1));`

Please have a look at [How to verify static void method has been called with power mockito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18466198/how-to-verify-static-void-method-has-been-called-with-power-mockito)